# Record Type selection not working with inlineedit Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, record-type, inlineeditsupport, detail

I have a Visualforce page with inlineedit enabled.  I need to use this rather than the standard Salesforce edit page for reasons I won't go into here.

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">

 <apex:detail inlineEdit="true" />

</apex:page>
```

Everything is working fine: the Contact displays in Edit mode.  The problem is when I click the Change link next to the Record Type.

When I select a new record type, it does not give me any kind of error, but just doesn't update it.  Checking in the debug logs, the only event mentioned is the redirect back to the original page, so it's Salesforce's backend which is not handling this well.

If I remove the override and use the standard Salesforce edit page, the Record Type change occurs successfully.

Before I log a case and scream "bug", has anyone else encountered this kind of problem with the inlineedit functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that choosing the Record Type doesn't actually save the page, it just appends a parameter to the URL.

So in my controller extension I just check to see if that parameter exists and if it does, perform an update to the record with that ID.